# Git Rebase deleted current files

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I have been struggling with git rebase and not sure how it works. So, what I did is following steps:

```
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git checkout my-branch
git rebase origin/main
```

Then I got some message in console saying I need to resolve the conflicts before continuing. The problem is when I open the "red" file, none of the current change or incoming change is the code that I just modified before I rebase.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
.MuiSwitch-root .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked {
=======
/* .MuiSwitch-root .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked {
>>>>>>> cbfe089 (built skeleton for Settings Page)
    color: var(--primary-clr) !important;
}

.MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked .MuiSwitch-track {
    background-color: black !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    background: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #e9e9e9) !important;
<<<<<<< HEAD
}
=======
} */
>>>>>>> cbfe089 (built skeleton for Settings Page)
```

I made changes for the whole file and none of these are my current code.
Plus, I noticed some of the files I added are also nowhere to be found. I have no idea what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can help you with the conflicts themselves, but I can explain what rebase does and it might help you deal with it better next time. Let's say the state of your git history is this:

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g
               ^main          ^my-branch (HEAD)
```

You've been working on your branch so you're ahead of main by a few commits. Your recent work is in commits e, f, and g. Then you checkout main, setting HEAD to it.

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g
               ^main (HEAD)   ^my-branch
```

You pull origin/main. Turns out someone else has pushed updates, commits h, i and j.

```
a <- b <- c <- d <- e <- f <- g
               ^              ^my-branch
               |
               h <- i <- j
                         ^main (HEAD)
```

When you checked out my-branch and ran `git rebase origin/main`, it took commits e, f, and g and stuck them at the end of j:

```
a <- b <- c <- d 
               ^              
               |
               h <- i <- j <- e <- f <- g
                         ^main          ^my-branch (HEAD)
```

It does this by applying e/f/g one at a time on top of what's at j.
The problem is that if h/i/j modified the same files as e/f/g, then you have to manually resolve the conflicts. That's why you see code that's unfamiliar to you. Because you didn't write h/i/j, but it can still show up in the conflicts.

I unfortunately can't help with the missing files, that sounds like while resolving the conflicts you might have accidentally deleted your own changes (the stuff in e/f/g).

Comment: More likely, the OP is resolving something in the equivalent of commit `e` and that's *before* adding new files or other code that he sees as missing now. The other thing that happens—sometimes too often—is that when rebase is "re-applying" `e` here, it gets the matching lines wrong and thinks the original changes were to places that weren't changed (but if changed there, have the same *effect*).